Symmetric correspondence between two sets
Consider two intervals $\displaystyle A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. I want to define a correspondence $\displaystyle G:A\rightrightarrows B$ that satisfies the following two properties:

For any $\displaystyle a\in A$, $\displaystyle |G( a) |=\theta $ for some constant $\displaystyle \theta $, where I use $|G(a)|$ to denote the measure of $G(a)$

For any $\displaystyle b\in B$, the set $\displaystyle O_{b} =\{a:b\in G( a)\}$ has constant measure $\displaystyle \gamma $, i.e. $\displaystyle |O_{b} |=\gamma \ \forall b\in B$


In words, I am matching each element in $A$ to a set of elements in $B$, and I want it to be that each element in $A$ is matched to a set of the same size. I also want it to be that if you look at the all the elements in $A$ for which some $b$ is matched to, you get the same size set regardless of which $b$ you look at.
Does such a correspondence exist? Is it possible to characterize it explicitly?

What do you mean by "mass"? Do you just mean cardinality? If so, you're looking for the concept of a biregular graph.

Are you interested in finite or infinite sets? These are two entirely different cups of tea.

@IvanNeretin I mean infinite sets. Uncountably infinite, if that makes a difference.

Ok, so are $\theta$ and $\gamma$ infinite cardinals?

My apologies for not being clear. By mass I don't mean cardinality. I mean measure. For my purposes $A$ and $B$ can be thought of as intervals on the real line, so I just mean the length of the interval.

Please edit your question to include all these important details. Users shouldn't have to trawl through the comments to understand the question.

Note that if $A,B$ are intervals, then they have the same cardinality, so there is a bijection between them, which satisfies your condition with $\theta=\gamma=0$.

Edit: After discussion in the comments, I've realized that you're interested in a continuous version of this problem, while the answer I originally wrote addresses a discrete version. This updated answer addresses both versions.
A correspondence $G\colon A\rightrightarrows B$, i.e., a function $G\colon A\to \mathcal{P}(B)$, is "the same thing" as a binary relation $R\subseteq A\times B$.
Indeed, given a correspondence $G\colon A\to \mathcal{P}(B)$, we define the relation $R$ by $aRb$ if and only if $b\in G(a)$. And given a binary relation $R\subseteq A\times B$, we define the correspondence $G(a) = \{b\in B\mid aRb\}$. Now you can check that these constructions are inverses.
Phrased in terms of a binary relation $R$, your conditions look more symmetrical: There are constants $\theta$ and $\gamma$ such that for all $a\in A$, $|\{b\in B\mid aRb\}| = \theta$, and for all $b\in B$, $|\{a\in A\mid aRb\}| = \gamma$.
For any $A$ and $B$, such a correspondence with $\theta = \gamma = 0$ always exists, taking $R = \varnothing$. So to make the problem non-trivial, I'll assume that $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are fixed in advance.

In the finite discrete version of the problem, we have finite sets $A$ and $B$, and $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are natural numbers.
A triple $(A,B,R)$ with $R\subseteq A\times B$ is also called a bipartite graph, and bipartite graphs satisfying your conditions are called biregular. Or, more precisely, $(\theta,\gamma)$-biregular.
Given sets $A$ and $B$, if there exists a $(\theta,\gamma)$-biregular graph with vertex sets $A$ and $B$, then $\theta\leq |B|$, $\gamma\leq |A|$, and $\theta|A| = \gamma|B|$ (since $\theta|A| = \gamma|B| = |R|$).
Conversely, assuming $\theta\leq |B|$, $\gamma\leq |A|$, and $\theta|A| = \gamma|B|$, we can construct a $(\theta,\gamma)$-biregular graph on $A$ and $B$. Let $A = \{a_0,\dots,a_{m-1}\}$ and $B = \{b_0,\dots,b_{n-1}\}$. Connect vertex $a_i$ to vertices $b_{i\theta},b_{i\theta+1},\dots,b_{i\theta+\theta-1}$, where we reduce the subscripts mod $n$. Then each $a_i$ is connected to $\theta$ vertices in $B$ by construction, and since $m\theta = n\gamma$, the $n$ vertices in $B$ are each covered exactly $\gamma$ times.

In the continuous version, we have $\mu$-measurable sets $A$ and $B$, and $\theta$ and $\gamma$ are real numbers. We ask: is there a subset $R\subseteq A\times B$ such that for all $a\in A$, $\mu(\{b\in B\mid aRb\}) = \theta$, and for all $b\in B$, $\mu(\{a\in A\mid aRb\}) = \gamma$?
In the comments, you also said that we can take $A$ and $B$ to be intervals in the real line. Let's assume this, and that $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. One more reasonable assumption is that $R$ should also be measurable. Under these assumptions, the problem is pretty simple.
Let $\alpha = \mu(A)$ and $\beta = \mu(B)$. One immediate observation is that we must have $\theta\leq \beta$ and $\gamma\leq \alpha$.
Next, by Fubini's theorem, $$\mu(R) = \int_{a\in A} \int_{b\in B} 1_{aRb}\,d\mu\,d\mu = \int_{a\in A} \theta\,d\mu = \alpha\theta$$ and also $$\mu(R) = \int_{b\in B} \int_{a\in A} 1_{aRb}\,d\mu\,d\mu = \int_{b\in B} \gamma\,d\mu = \beta\gamma.$$
Thus $\alpha\theta = \beta\gamma$.
Conversely, suppose $\theta\leq \beta$, $\gamma\leq \alpha$, and $\alpha\theta = \beta\gamma$. If any of these constants are $0$, we can take $R = \varnothing$. So assume they are non-zero, and let $\delta = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{\theta}{\gamma}$.
After shifting, we can assume $A = (0,\alpha)$ and $B = (0,\beta)$. Let $R_1$ be the subset of $A\times B$ bounded below by the line $y = \delta x$ and above by the line $y = \delta x + \theta$. Let $R_2$ be the subset of $A\times B$ bounded above by the line $y = \delta(x-\alpha)+\theta$.

Then $R = R_1\cup R_2$ satisfies your conditions.

This is very helpful. The condition $\theta |A| = \gamma |B|$ makes sense. Now my only question is, as you say, if that is sufficient. And if not, what conditions would be sufficient.

@cruijf I updated my answer.
